# in sql server all conditions are not firing?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_HM_InsertSetterGetterAllocationDet]
@type varchar(50),
@name varchar(50),
@settingdate datetime,
@quantity int,
@Batchno varchar(50),
@pulloutdate datetime,

@supervisor varchar(50),
@updatedby varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

   if exists(select * from K_HM_SetterGetterAllocationDet where Name=@name and      [type]=@type and Attrited='false')
   begin
       select '1' as status
   end
   else 
      if exists (select * from K_HM_GetterSetterDet where Capacity >=@quantity)
      begin
         select '2' as status
      end
      else 
         insert into K_HM_SetterGetterAllocationDet (Type, Name, Settingdate, Quantity, batchno,pulloutdate,Supervisor,Attrited,Updatedby,Updatedon) 
         values (@type, @name,  @settingdate, @quantity, @Batchno, @pulloutdate, @supervisor, 'false',   @updatedby, getdate())   

   select '3' as status
END
```

in above procedure, 3rd case not executing when above two cases are false and Quantity is less than Capacity. Quantity less than or greater than capacity it is always entering into 2nd case only. What's wrong in my procedure, please help me....

Comment: what is the max value of Capacity in table K_HM_GetterSetterDet and which value are you passing to quantity parameter ?

Comment: I've corrected the indentation to match the structure of the query - personally I try to always use `BEGIN`...`END` blocks for all branches of `if`...`else` - does the revealed structure match your expectations?

Comment: Not sure why your conditionals aren't working, but you need to put the insert and select '3' inside a BEGIN...END, otherwise you're always going to get two 'Status' results

Comment: i am passing int as parameter to quantity, for different names different capacity is there.

Comment: Also, we don't know the structure of your tables, but that second `exists` looks suspect - "is there *any* row in `K_HM_GetterSetterDet` which has a `capacity` greater than `@quantity`?" - and ignoring all other columns.

Comment: K_HM_GetterSetter table consits capacity column and Quantity is another table column

Comment: But does `K_HM_GetterSetterDet` contain only one row? Or do you really intend to test *all* rows in that table? I'd have usually expected some other comparison operation in the `WHERE` clause to be more selective about *which* rows in that table you want to test the `Capacity` of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_HM_InsertSetterGetterAllocationDet]
@type varchar(50),
@name varchar(50),
@settingdate datetime,
@quantity int,
@Batchno int,
@pulloutdate datetime,

@supervisor varchar(50),
@updatedby varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

  if exists(select * from K_HM_SetterGetterAllocationDet where Name=@name and [type]=@type and Attrited='false')
 begin 
 select '1' as status
 end





else  
begin 
if exists (select * from K_HM_GetterSetterDet where Capacity >@quantity  and Name=@name   ) 
begin
select '2' as status
insert into K_HM_SetterGetterAllocationDet       (Type,Name,Settingdate,Quantity,batchno,pulloutdate,Supervisor,Attrited,Updatedby,Updatedon)  values
 ( @type, @name, @settingdate, @quantity, @Batchno, @pulloutdate, @supervisor, 'false', @updatedby,  getdate())
end

else 
begin

select '3' as status
end
end
END
```

with this procedure is working correctly....

Answer (score 0):

I have added a `Begin...End` on the 3rd statement.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT    *
              FROM      K_HM_SetterGetterAllocationDet
              WHERE     Name = @name
                        AND [type] = @type
                        AND Attrited = 'false' ) 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  '1' AS status
    END
  ELSE 
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  * FROM    K_HM_GetterSetterDet WHERE   Capacity >= @quantity ) 
        BEGIN
            SELECT  '2' AS status
        END
    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            INSERT  INTO K_HM_SetterGetterAllocationDet
                    ( Type ,
                      Name ,
                      Settingdate ,
                      Quantity ,
                      batchno ,
                      pulloutdate ,
                      Supervisor ,
                      Attrited ,
                      Updatedby ,
                      Updatedon
                    )
            VALUES  ( @type ,
                      @name ,
                      @settingdate ,
                      @quantity ,
                      @Batchno ,
                      @pulloutdate ,
                      @supervisor ,
                      'false' ,
                      @updatedby ,
                      GETDATE()
                    )                         
            SELECT  '3' AS STATUS
        END
```

**EDIT**: Based on comments...

Take each query..

```
SELECT  *
FROM    K_HM_SetterGetterAllocationDet
WHERE   Name = 'hardcoded name'
        AND [type] = 'hardcoded type'
        AND Attrited = 'false'
```

if this has rows, then `status =1`, otherwise run the below...

```
SELECT  *
FROM    K_HM_GetterSetterDet
WHERE   Capacity >= hardcoded quantity
```

if this has rows, then `status = 2`, otherwise `status = 3`

Comment: when you run this SP with the different tests, are you seeing the `status` in the result? and if so, what are the params you're supplying when the expected status is incorrect?

Comment: am passing quantity less than capacity at that time status 3 had to call But, it's not like that always going to 2nd status only

Comment: if you're passing `quantity` as less, then it will go to 2 `Capacity >= @quantity`

Comment: what i mean, if capacity is 1000 for that selected name, i am inserting quantity 500 at that time status 3 has to execute but it is executing status 2

Comment: This `SELECT  * FROM    K_HM_GetterSetterDet WHERE   Capacity >= @quantity` will find any item, since you're not checking for a name.  The logic is incorrect, but it's hard to know what the logic needs to be.  Run each of the selects and hardcode the values, so you can see if you get records at each step...